# Scipy fitting does not converge well, neither does it give sensible error estimates

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, model-fitting

I'm using `scipy.optimize.leastsq` to estimate best fit parameters as well as errors on those parameters. I have few parameters in my fit, and the estimate for most of those parameters turn out to be reasonably well. However, one of my parameters gives me the final result of what I entered as my initial guess. Say my guess was `5.2`, it returns be best fit estimate of `5.2+-0.0010`. The same would apply whatever my initial guess is. Two concerns are the final result being initial result or extremely close to the result, and extremely small error estimate. Could anyone suggest me what the problem might be?

Comment: As I recall, if no improvement in the parameter can be found then the initial parameter estimate is returned. That is, any change results in higher error. You can verify this by manually calculating the sum-of-squared errors using (A) the final parameters and then (B) the final parameters with this one parameter changed by +/- 0.001

Comment: It is impossible to provide meaningful help from the vague description you mention. Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).